# C# Binary Search on 2 indexes

Tags: c#, algorithm, search, binary-search, icomparable

I have an object with attributes ; startIndex, endIndex

I am able to do binary search based on startIndex by implementing the following :

```
        int IComparable.CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            Repeat r = (Repeat)obj;
            return this.startIndex.CompareTo(r.startIndex);
        }
```

However with the same Repeat Object I d like to do binary search also on the end index separately.

How can i do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to use the typed version of IComparable, such as IComparable<Repeat> which would define a CompareTo(Repeat r) rather than the untyped object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the `Array.BinarySearch()` or `List<T>.BinarySearch()` methods, you can use the overload that takes an `IComparer` or `IComparer<T>`. Then you can implement the comparison semantics in a separate class and pass it in when you want to do a search.

Comment: I m using List<Repeat>. I see that binary search on list also takes an IComparer. So that should be it?